# Is there a time when a superclass's constructor is not called in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

This question got me in an interview. If B is A's subclass. When constructing B, is there a time when A's constructor is not called?

EDIT: I told the interviewer that I couldn't think of such case because I thought it would only make sense for a superclass to be constructed properly before constructing the subclass.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was your answer?

Comment: I wonder what places still use edge-case trivia of C++ as a form of interview questions.  Under what circumstances in coding would it be important to know the answer to this question, if the answer is yes.

Comment: @Andy Finkenstadt, it might be useful for flushing out someone who calls themselves an "expert" without deserving the term.

Comment: @Mark, I edited the question. If there's no way to do so, then I think the interviewer might be looking at my thought process.

Comment: if this is something related to thought process, I have some interesting answer. Check it below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible instance is when both `A` and `B` have no user-declared constructors and an instance of `B` is being *value-initialized*.

`A` and `B` both have implicitly declared constructors which wouldn't be used in this initialization.

Similarly if `A` has no user-declared constructor but appears in the member initializer list of a constructor of `B` but with an empty initializer then `A` will be *value-initialized* when this constructor of `B` is used. Again, because `A` has not user-declared constructors the *value-initialization* doesn't use a constructor.

Comment: I would have thought from the context of the question that `A` had a constructor, but this is a neat loophole.

Comment: @Mark: A does have a constructor. It doesn't have a user-defined constructor :-)

Comment: I did not realize that in the final case (your last paragraph) `A` would be strictly value-initialized if present with an empty initializer in a `B` constructor's initializer list.  In fact if anything, I would sooner assume such a presence to be an explicit default constructor call.  The more you know...

Comment: What does _value-initialized_ mean? I guess it means implicitly generated copy constructor that is also constructor and it is called (not necessarily via `call` asm instruction or something but it is called in terms of language semantics).

Comment: For a class with no user-declared constructors, value-initialized means value-initialize all of the classes bases and members. It happens instead of a constructor call. Right at this moment I don't have the standard to reference at hand.

Comment: To value-initialize an object of type T:
— if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the
default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
constructor)
— if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
called
— if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
— otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

Comment: Seems to me that A's constructor is indeed called.  The behavior is certainly the same.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Strictly speaking you are right. Must admit I didn't know that C++ standard contained such bizarre features and terminology. Though value initialisation appears to be almost identical to default constructor call (and it is identical if constructor is explicitly defined) and it anyway implies calling all direct and indirect base-classes'/non-static-members' explicit constructors. So it is more like scholastic answer. Anyway you are right.

Comment: @Ben: the behavior is not the same. With value-initialization, any `int` member is set to 0. The default generated constructor doesn't (necessarily) do this.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you could do something that throws an exception while generating the parameters for a non-default constructor for A in B's initialization list?

You can see below that the constructor for A is never called because an exception occurs in the parameters generation for it

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int f()
{
    throw "something"; // Never throw a string, just an example
}


class A
{
public:
    A(int x) { cout << "Constructor for A called\n"; }
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A(f()) {}
};


int main()
{
    try 
    {
        B b;
    }
    catch (const char* ex) 
    {
        cout << "Exception: " << ex << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: But construction of B never happens either.

Comment: @unapersson: construction of `B` is started (but doesn't return). So the conditions of the question are satisfied.

Comment: @JohnB: Brilliant answer. At first I didn't notice this.

Comment: I think technically the construction of `B` has not started yet; the construction of `A` is a kind of pre-condition. It's still an interesting edge case.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: "kind of pre-condition" It is not precondition. It is necessary part of the construction process. If you use specific constructor anywhere in the program (e.g. initialization of base/member, initialization of simple object, creating temporary object in some expression, new expression) you always mean all construction steps - not just executing constructor function's body.

Comment: Along similar lines, it's possible that construction throws for an earlier base, i.e. `class B : X, A { ... }` (which I'd argue is not excluded by the question).

Answer (score 2):

**Virtual Inheritance**.

```
struct B {...};
struct D1 : virtual B {...};
struct D2 : virtual B {...};
struct Child : D1, D2 {...};
```

Normally the constructor `B()` should have been called twice, but it will be called only once.

Comment: This is the example I was going to give.  Normally construction of `B` happens during construction of `D1`, but with virtual inheritance, construction of `B` happens during construction of `Child` and `D1::D1` does not call its base class constructor.

Comment: I also considered this, but rejected it.  The base class constructor is still called, which satisfies the query in the question's title.  From the text of the Q - "When constructing B, is there a time when A's constructor is not called?" - that's a little more ambiguous, as it's unclear whether/how the "when constructing" puts a limitation on the timeframe under consideration.  Worth listing anyway, fleshing out the problem space....

Comment: @Tony, Here the base class would have constructed for normal inheritance; but with `virtual` inheritance it's constructing only once. So at least one of the derived classes is loosing its base class construction.

Comment: iammilind: how is that perspective more compelling than considering the base class to be shared between the derived classes?

Answer (score 0):

Construction of B can't even start until A is fully constructed, so the answer is **no**.

Comment: I guess you mean that B constructor function body is not entered before A is fully constructed and that is true. But surely construction of B object starts before even first initialization-list expression is executing. So you are wrong.

Comment: I believe one of the first steps of creating a particular object is creation of all its subobjects, including super types. One of the last steps is actually entering its constructor.

Comment: @Serge Dundich, the order of construction is very well specified by the standard. Perhaps you are using too loose a definition for "construction" - for example, reserving the memory for the object is not included.

Comment: "Perhaps you are using too loose a definition" Not really. Reserving the memory is not included indeed but constructing base classes and non-static members are included. Executing constructor function's boby is just a final step. Construction of the object is everything that happens when you use placement new (it is like pure construction - without memory allocation).

Answer (score 0):

If B has a second superclass that gets constructed before A, there will be a period where A's constructor has not yet been called although it is going to be.